# What's the inverse of the X mnemonic in chmod?

Tags: command, chmod

Is there a way other than `find … -type f -exec chmod -x {} +` to *remove* the `x` bit from `u`, `g` and/or `o` recursively with *just* `chmod`?

The `X` mnemonic in `chmod` allows one to recursively set permissions on a folder hierarchy and set the `x` flag on folders, but not on files.

Now if I'd like to **remove** the `x` flag on everything *but* the folders, is there a concise way of expressing that, analogous to the above mentioned `X`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can clear all `x` bits and then set them on directories, like this.

```
chmod -R ugo-x,ugo+X .
```

Comment: Hmm, hadn't thought of that one. Good point.